# org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper 147 - Packet for query is too large

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I'm getting the below error when doing DB query using hibernate where it says the packet for query is too large. I don't quite understand from where it is coming.

> 21-07-2015 13:36:10,615  INFO [http-bio-9091-exec-7]
>   com.aricent.aricloud.util.LoggerAspect 47 - Entered class
>   com.aricent.aricloud.dao.AricloudDAOImpl Method   checkUserName
>   21-07-2015 13:36:10,626  WARN [http-bio-9091-exec-7]
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper 145 - SQL Error: 0,
>   SQLState: S1000
>  21-07-2015 13:36:10,630 ERROR
>   [http-bio-9091-exec-7]
>   **org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper 147 - Packet for query is too large (1083 > 1024). You can change this value on the
>   server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.**

I have set the variable **max_allowed_packet=40M** , but the packet seems to take 1024 as value. Where is this value coming from?

Here is my method for select calling on which the issue is happening. The UserEntity table has only 13 rows in it and no other tables are having much data. If I restart mysql the application starts working, Please let me know how to fix the issue permanently ?

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public UserEntity checkUserName(String userName) {
    Session session = mySessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query q = session.createQuery("SELECT e FROM UserEntity e WHERE userName = :userName");
    q.setParameter(USER_NAME, userName);

    List<UserEntity> list = q.list();
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        return list.get(0);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is correct, and you set right variable. Maybe you set it in wrong config file and mysql does not apply new settings. Try to connect to server and run command `show variables like 'max_allowed_packet'`

Comment: I have checked the same already and it's giving me the correct value only 40*1024*1024

Comment: I met the same issue. Do you have a solution @bagui ?

Comment: I didn't get any particular solution. But when I upgraded till MySQL v5.5 this issue is gone. seems to the issue with 5.1 v

Answer (score -1):

> You must increase this value if you are using large BLOB columns or
>   long strings. It should be as big as the largest BLOB you want to use.
>   The protocol limit for max_allowed_packet is 1GB. The value should be
>   a multiple of 1024; nonmultiples are rounded down to the nearest
>   multiple.

Comment: Hi, 
for my current application and db schema I'm not using any large blob. I'm interested to know why this scenario is coming where is very small amount of data in my db. also mysql suggests to make the change as I did https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html